# Port 80 stopped responding using Ubuntu 18.04 on Compute Engine

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, port, google-compute-engine

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 on GCP Compute Engine.

A simple go lang server listens to port 80 and responds to browser requests.

I was able to connect to the server on the Internet for a day.  I stopped the instance couple of times and started. Now port 80 doesn't respond any more and browser times out.

When I start the program, there are no errors reported and my println statement in server faithfully prints a message "listening to port 80".

How can I troubleshoot this problem? Is there a problem with port 80 on Ubuntu?

Also ssh stopped responding. I can only use the web console.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you assign your instance a static IP address, your instance has an ephemeral IP address. Stopping your instance releases an ephemeral address. When you start your instance again you are assigned a new address.

The solution is either to use the new IP address or to change the address to be static.

- Go to the Google Cloud Console -> Compute Engine.
- Make a note of the external IP address.
- Go to VPC Network -> External IP addresses.
- Locate the IP address assigned to your instance. Under the type column, click on 
  "Ephermal" and change to "Static".

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. Thanks!